# Calculate time with JPA or native query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I want to use Hibernate `current_timestamp()` to write a timestamp based on the database time to a column. I want to use the database time, not the system time of the system of my service that uses the database. I am using the database time for two queries, *Lock* and *Unlock*.

**Lock query**

`UPDATE MyEntity e SET e.lock = current_timestamp() WHERE e.id = :id`

**Unlock query**

`UPDATE MyEntity e SET e.lock = (current_timestamp() - "30 seconds") WHERE e.id = :id`

My last resort is to use a native query for PostgreSQL like this:

`SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '30 second')`

I am unable to locate the documentation on how to add/subtract time,if it is even supported. How can I build the *Unlock* query?

Comment: Afaik there is no support yet for it...
jpa 2.1 introduced the FUNC('functionName', args) to call a specific db function, but it's still obviously db dependent

Comment: Just a note: you should set both service and db to use Utc and save yourself a lot of headaches

Comment: Thanks. We are using UTC everywhere but I'm still worried about different instances being on diferent clocks.

Comment: _Calculate time with JPA or native query_ So do accept also native query? For the unlock part?

Comment: @pirho Yes, native queries is what I have as work around now. I would be willing to accept it as an answer if JPA does not support this yet.

Comment: @span So is your  _Unlock query_ something you are using or does it not work/update the `lock` field?

Comment: The only solution I can think of that isn't a native query is to have a table trigger check the field on insert/update and change it to the current one if it's null, then just set it to null through JPA. That, however is much harder to write (and maintain, unless your project uses a lot of database triggers) than a native query. Also it might not work if the constraints are checked before the trigger fires, which I'm not sure of.

Comment: And what is your `JPA` version?

Comment: @pirho I can use any JPA version. The native query I have now "works" but I would love a solution that does not depend on native queries.

Answer (score 2):

set the default value of the column to the (your database specific) currenttime value.
With MySql,
the column would look like this:

```
column_name DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**Edit**

Here is an example (MySql) that will update the datetime column every time the row is updated:

```
last_update DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Comment: Thanks although I'm not sure how this can be used to update a row using a lock/unlock query.